# Display speed on mkmap - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, dictionary, cllocationmanager

When running this log:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

NSLog(@" new -> %@ \n old -> %@",(newLocation),(oldLocation));
```

i get:

> new -> <+37.33328787,-122.05209673> +/- 5.00m (speed 33.57 mps / course 254.88) @ 9/30/12, 9:53:15 AM Eastern European Summer Time
>
> old -> <+37.33336511,-122.05174034> +/- 5.00m (speed 33.73 mps / course 255.23) @ 9/30/12, 9:53:14 AM Eastern European Summer Time

How can I display, in real time, speed shown by "mps" (meters per second) on a UILabel?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLLocation` has a property `speed`. Assuming you want to display `location`'s `speed` in `label`, do something like:

```
NSString *speedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Speed is %.2f meters per second.",location.speed];
label.text = speedString;
```

You can find out about more properties of `CLLocation` or any class by searching the documents in Xcode with cmd-option-shift-?, or my searching the internet for "CLLocation class reference". You can quickly scan the outline at the top of these documents for things that might answer your question. Oftentimes, methods and properties related to similar tasks are grouped together. This makes it easy to quickly find out if a class can meet your needs.

Hope this helps!